# Accessing Request POST Body from WordPress/PHP Code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

The Wordpress `get_query_var`method allows to access variables supplied in the URL, as query parameters.
While this works great for many situations, I need to post some data that I would prefer not to include in the URL header.

Is there another method to obtain that data? I was looking in the list of methods from WordPress, but it is not that easy to find that needle in the haystack... specially when post is used with other semantics all over the documentation :-)